# Tyan Motherboard - S28891 - continuous beep, still boots - can't figure out what the beep means

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a server that has a Tyan motherboard - S2891G2NR - when starting up, it has a continuous beep (from the instant it powers on) - it still boots just fine, but the beep never goes away.  I looked on the LCD readout and it says F6 - which looks like it might be normal (Manual says F6h means "Clear Huge Segment" not sure if that is the same as just f6).  Booted into the RAID bios as well and all drives report ok - no error lights either.  How can I determine what this beep means and to clear it?  It's kept in an air conditioned room where the temperature is 65 degrees.  I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server on it.

Comment: This should be asked on superuser!

Comment: ok, thanks, wasn't sure - I'll try over there as well.

Comment: It's probably a case lock alarm. See if you can find something in the BIOS for "Case"/"Panel" and "Alarm"/"Switch"/"Lock".

Comment: The intrusion detection isn't hooked up for this server.  The server was functioning fine for months, came in this morning and it was powered off - powered it on and there is this constant alarm sound.  Seems like it might be CPU temps, but they look ok in BIOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it - and it was a really dumb 'problem' - turns out one of the power supplies (it has two) was not plugged in - this was causing the alarm.

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem like this once and the solution was to disable the Fan Alarms in the BIOS.

Well, the real fix was to replace the bad fan, but the beep was the result of the alarm option being set. :)

Note that a fan failure doesn't necessarily mean that one of the fans isn't turning. If there's a bad bearing the fan could appear to be running but is actually running far more slowly than it should, which will also trigger the alarm.